# Problem with storing german words into the MySql DB....?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am facing an small issue in my project When I am trying to ***store some German words*** into the **MYSQL Database**. When this ***German words contains umlauts*** i.e. characters ä, ö, ß, ü etc., **they are not stored as they are**.....?

I want to ***store them as it is*** into the Database.To do so I tried to change the `COLLATION to UTF8-general-ci, and others in the list using PHP myAdmin`. But none of them is working for me.

Am I in the right way or I have to do something else.

Please suggest some help.

Thanks In Advance......

Comment: DUP DUP DUP search internazionalization php utf-8 here or google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

years ago I've faced the same problem. I've solved it by implicit setting NAMES option for mysql. In my code it looks like this:

//inside AbstractMapper class

```
public function __construct($modelClass, $dbTable) {
$this->setDbTable($dbTable);
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->getDbTable()->getAdapter(), 'set names utf8');
$stmt->execute();
$this->_model_class = $modelClass;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose the right transfer encoding either. Call

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

before inserting the data and make sure that the german words are utf8-encoded before inserting.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [utf8_encode($string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to encode your text into UTF8 first, before saving it into the database. In order for characters to display correctly in a certain language, you have to (1) set the text into the right charset and then also (2) set a database to the right charset (as you did).

Also, for example, file `display.php` will output the German text, you can open the file in any editors (EmEditor?) and then "save as", choose a right encoding scheme. After that, the display file, when outputting the text, will take care of the charset.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to the database, use the following codes:

```
SET NAMES XXX
```

replace XXX with your working charset.